# Override "permission denied"

Tags: linux, wget, file-permissions, simplehttpserver

I want to upload a file from my linux OS to a shell therefore I started a http server. While uploading via wget it gives me a error "Permission Denied"!!! Any solutions

Tried updog and simplehttp server but no avail. Even netcat and curl to extract the info. It does not help by changing folder permissions (chmod 777).

Comment: Whilst using http server is possible solution for file transfer it is not only one available, if you are not strictly limited to it I suggest trying [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)